# How to open nodes in jstree using an array of ids?

Tags: javascript, jstree

I am using jstree javascript plugin and I am loading data asynchronously. I am trying to implement search on this tree's data. I have a web service that returns an array of ids based on the search parameter. The tree is not loaded before search. When the user clicks on search, based on the ids returned I am trying to load/open the nodes in the tree one by one corresponding to the id.

```
for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
     $("#tree").jstree("open_node", document.getElementById(ids[i]));
}
```

However, only the root node is being loaded. Can anybody suggest a simple function to load the nodes one by one using an array of ids?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the jsTree is not loaded that you can use "state" => "open" for the node you want to be open on load when building data for jsTree. See the example below - code copied from http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data

```
{
    "data" : "node_title",
    // omit `attr` if not needed; the `attr` object gets passed to the jQuery `attr` function
    "attr" : { "id" : "node_identificator", "some-other-attribute" : "attribute_value" },
    // `state` and `children` are only used for NON-leaf nodes
    "state" : "closed", // or "open", defaults to "closed"
    "children" : [ /* an array of child nodes objects */ ]
}
```